# No answer trying to execute driver.execute_script(gooogletag

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying get some response in the console from the browser when I run the googletag parameters with Selenium but unfortunately I don't.

I have already tried with `.execute_async_script('googletag.pubads()')` as also as put everything in a try/execute but the execute is never being called even when I don't get any answer back.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

url = 'https://joursferies.fr'

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
browser = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
browser.get(url)
browser.execute_script('googletag.openConsole()')

# Until here everything is perfect but with the following line is when I never get any answer:

browser.execute_script('googletag.pubads()')
```

I expected that the Console in the Browser Inspect would show me the information but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

try to add return,   `browser.execute_script('return googletag.openConsole()')`

Comment: @error404 If this answer was helpful to you upvote or accept the answer for the benefit of future readers. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote